# Django not retaining session while in iframe

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

I'm developing an application for Bitrix24 and I'm having a problem with sessions.

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class IndexView(View):
    r'''Index View.'''

    def get(self, request):
        r'''Manages Bitrix24 authentication redirect.'''

        return render(request, 'frontend/index.html')

    # POST working as GET because Bitrix24 does not GET the homepage.
    def post(self, request):
        r'''Renders the home page and stores Bitrix24 domain in session.'''

        request.session['bitrix24_domain'] = request.GET.get('DOMAIN')
        return render(request, 'frontend/index.html')
```

As soon as the user goes to another view, the session is gone, completely. It also happens locally, if I set a key in session and try to retrieve it from another page, all data is lost too.

I'm currently using default settings to Django and using rest-framework.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT**

I tried using self.request.session and it worked, but doesn't make sense to me. Can anyone explain?

**EDIT**

I've noticed that I can't login users while my app is in an `iframe` inside Bitrix24, for example. How do I store things in session in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django CSP (`pip install django-csp`) along with `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None` does the trick.

For django-csp:

```
CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ["'self'"]
CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS = ["'self'", 'https://*.example.com']
```

This would allow Django app to be displayed in all example.com subdomains.